# How can I create a destructor method using pyo3 in Rust when creating a Python class?

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I'm using pyo3 in Rust to create a Python module.
I can create a class, and a constructor with:

```rust
    #[pyclass]
    struct MyClass {
        i: u8,
    }

    #[pymethods]
    impl MyClass {
        #[new]
        fn new() -> PyResult<Self> {
            println!("Instance Constructed!");
            Ok(MyClass { i: 0 })
        }

        // Doesn't work
        fn __del__(&mut self) {
            println!("Instance destroyed");
        }
    }

    #[pymodule]
    fn myclass(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
        m.add_class::<MyClass>()?;
        Ok(())
    }
```

When I compile it, and use my class from Python, I can see that my instance has a `__del__` method, and I can call it manually, but Python won't call it when the instance is being destroyed:

```py
>>> from myclass import MyClass
>>> inst = MyClass()
Instance Constructed!
>>> inst.__del__
<built-in method __del__ of builtins.MyClass object at 0x766ca4c0>
>>> inst.__del__()
Instance destroyed
>>> del(inst)
>>>
```

Is there a special way to create a destructor in Rust using pyo3?
Why would Python not call `__del__`? It seems to have no problems calling it for a class defined in pure Python when you `del` the instance.

Comment: Have you tried just implementing `Drop`? Also `__del__` is not really a destructor, because if the object is involved in a cycle it'll be invoked whenever python comes around to breaking the cycle. It's closer to a *finalizer*.

Comment: @Masklinn what is `Drop`? Some sort of Python dunder method? A `pyo3` macro, like `#[new]`? A `pyo3` trait? A rust `std` trait? Is it [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html)? How would one implement it? Are there any examples or documentation?

Comment: @Masklinn it appears that implementing `std::ops::Drop` on my class does indeed work. Is this the expected way to create a destructor when working with `pyo3`? I'm still not sure why `__del__` isn't being executed. It doesn't appear that my simple test case has any cycles that would prevent the instance from being deleted immediately upon calling `del`. If I understand you correctly, a cycle would be some sort of cyclic reference of the instance to itself, or something like that. Or does it?

Comment: `__del__` is a Python-level hook, pyo3 works at a lower level, that of the C API which uses the `tp_dealloc` slot.  It makes a lot of sense that they'd elect to simply map `tp_dealloc` to `Drop` as that means things would usually work out of the box e.g. if you store a `Vec` in your structure, it will get properly cleaned up without having to do anything.

Comment: As for cycles, yes, if an object refers to itself, or an object refers to an other which refers back to it, or through more intermediates, you have a *cycle*. Because CPython uses *reference-counting*, object in a cycle will all have a reference count of 1 even if the cycle is isolated from everything else (and thus "garbage"). For that purpose Python has a limited GC process which tries to find cycles and break them (by setting one of the reference in the cycle to `None` somewhat randomly).

Comment: Ok, well the solution seems to work pretty good. If you want to write a short answer, I can give you credit if you'd like. Plus it will make it more obvious for others looking for an answer to the problem that there's a solution

Comment: Hi @John, if you don't mind sharing your implementation for `Drop`?

Comment: @Jim Any drop impl is going to look the same: `impl Drop for MyClass {
    fn drop(&mut self) { /* do stuff here */ } }`  To replace his __del__ attempt in the question, just put the contents from there in the middle here...

Answer (score 1):

When the Python object is released (after `__del__`, when the `tp_dealloc()` slot is called on the wrapper object) the underlying Rust struct will be dropped, so if you implement trait `Drop` for the struct it should be called as you expect.

*(I consider this a placeholder answer, capturing info in the comments on the original question. Happy to delete this if @Masklinn would like to provide an official answer.  I just didn't want others to miss this info if they happen not to read the comments.)*